# Django field formatting within template defined within the field

Tags: django, django-models

I have a custom field called Percentage which I would like displayed in Django templates always with a % sign, so if the DB is holding a Float of 100.00 then in the template it would always render as 100%.

I know I can write a template tag however I would like this change to be made globally so I don't need to do template tags everywhere.  I've seen packages like dj-money do this so that 1 is formatted as $1 automatically.  I've looked at the code but can't see exactly how this is occuring.

I've investigated methods like `to_python`, `__str__` and `__unicode__` on the field but these don't appear to work.  How can I customise the field to always format a particular way in string based situations like django templates and django admin?

At present I've just created a custom method per field on the model to do the formatting, however I fee like there should be a way to set this on the field level.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this :

```
class Percentage(models.Model):
    percentage = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.percentage}%'
```

or

```
class Percentage(models.Model):
    percentage = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.percentage}%'
```

Comment: No I didn't, this will only be called when `__str__ ` is being called on the model, but I'm looking for the method that is called on the field